# How to include output when saving history as notebook in iPython

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I do not seem to be able to get output to be included in a .ipynb that is created with the

```
  %notebook -e tmp.ipynb
```

magic command.
When I create a simple function that should produce output, f, I can save it with the

```
%history -o -f history.test
```

magic command, and successfully see the output :

```
f = lambda x : x + 2
/f 1
3.
```

However, when I try the same using the above %notebook magic command, I get the following :

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 1,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "f = lambda x : x + 2"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 2,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "/f 1"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 3,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "%history -o -f history.test"
   ]
  }
 ],
 "metadata": {},
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 0
}.
```

Has anyone encountered this problem? Is this a problem, even? or a feature of iPython? It doesn't seem to be clear from the documentation, but I have clearly seen embedded iPython notebook HTML in blogs that have output lines.
I should note I do not have any custom *config* files in my .ipython/profile_default directory.